# Should [microsoft-flow] and [ms-flow] be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

There seems to be no difference between them:

[microsoft-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-flow)
[ms-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-flow)

Comment: They renamed it, [powerautomate] is the correct tag.  You can ask for synonyms.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned by [Hans Passant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) in [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391707/should-microsoft-flow-and-ms-flow-be-merged#comment742345_391707), both of these tags are incorrect.

There is now a [powerautomate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerautomate) tag which refers to the new name, which is unfortunate, as Stack Overflow typically uses a hyphen to join words.

I propose we create a [power-automate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/power-automate) tag, and synonymize [powerautomate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerautomate), [microsoft-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-flow), and [ms-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-flow) to that new tag. We can copy the excerpt and wiki from the [powerautomate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerautomate) tag.

[Erik A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-a) mentions in the comments that the other apps in Microsoft's "Power Platform" do not have the hyphen. That's unfortunate, as I find multiple words of a single case harder to read. In any case, we can certainly keep [powerautomate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerautomate) and synonymize the flow tags with that one... As long as we rename [power-bi-report-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/power-bi-report-server) to [powerbi-report-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-report-server).

Comment: I don't think we should hyphenate here. PowerAutomate is positioned next to PowerBI and PowerApps, which both already have tags without a hyphen (and while Microsoft uses a space in the name, I see it without a space more often).

Comment: @ErikA It would be nice if MS themselves were more consistent in their own naming conventions. PowerShell, PowerPoint, PowerToys, but Power Pivot, Power BI, Power Automate. :(.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Or even if they stopped renaming things for no reason

Comment: I named the [tag:powerautomate] tag with one word rather than hyphenated based on the precedent of [tag:powerapps] and [tag:powerbi] (and [tag:powerquery] and [tag:powerpivot]). I felt it was more important to keep consistency within that family of technologies than it was to have a renamed technology in this case be different from the rest of its tech family. Perhaps if Shog is feeling benevolent he might do a rename on the backend of each tag for us... re: this, I agree we should synonymize [tag:microsoft-flow] with [tag:powerautomate], but [tag:ms-flow] has few enough remaining questions...

Comment: (cont'd) ...that we can just replace them with [tag:powerautomate]. I think I have it down to about 20 or so as of where I last left off working on the tags since the name change was announced at MS Ignite.

Comment: @James Yes, renaming things can be frustrating, but in this case it really did need renaming. Not only was it the only member of the Power family that didn't have "Power" in its name, but it was also called something so generic that trying to use it in prose was almost impossible: "To do this, build a Flow flow that simulates a work flow..." etc. Power Automate is a much better name on all accounts (and it more accurately represents the product as what it is: an automation tool rather than a workflow engine).

Comment: Done, and done. But I didn't change [power-bi-report-server], since that's the actual name, including spaces.